# ParametricPlot3D crashes Kernel when called repeatedly in loop

Tags: plotting, list-manipulation, animation, kernel, parametric-functions

I have a parametric function `surf[u,v]`. It can be plotted successfully like this: `ParametricPlot3D[surf[u, v], {u, 0, 6 Pi *0.7}, {v, 0, 2 Pi}]`

However, I would like to make a series of plots, incrementally changing umax. I tried this with a for loop as well as table, like this:

```
nn = 24;
Table[ParametricPlot3D[surf[u,v],{u,0,6 Pi*i/nn},{v,0,2Pi}],{i,1,nn,1}]
```

Unfortunately, every time I run this, it crashes the Kernel without finishing. I tried running a similar command with a simpler parametric surface, which finishes successfully and without crash:

```
nn = 24;
Table[ParametricPlot3D[{Cos[u], Sin[u] + Cos[v], Sin[v]}, {u, 0, 
   2 \[Pi] i/nn}, {v, -\[Pi], \[Pi]}], {i, 1, nn, 1}]
```

So the problem must be with my surface. I am using Mathematica 10.2.0.0 on Linux (64-bit). Here is the full code causing the premature Kernel quit:

```
surf[u_, v_] := {Cos[
    u] (16.958793136378254` E^(0.16568669119550355` u) + \
(1.2436985521695564`*^-15 + 
        8.299999999999999` E^(0.16568669119550355` u) + 
        0.34091663610461015` Sqrt[
          8.881784197001252`*^-16 + 
           5.927385595690565` E^(0.16568669119550355` u)] Cos[
          0.0027916963719975653` + 
           179.1021065468981` Log[
             1.4984319905657307`*^-16 + 
              1.` E^(0.16568669119550355` u)]]) Sin[v]), 
  Sin[u] (16.958793136378254` E^(0.16568669119550355` u) + \
(1.2436985521695564`*^-15 + 
        8.299999999999999` E^(0.16568669119550355` u) + 
        0.34091663610461015` Sqrt[
          8.881784197001252`*^-16 + 
           5.927385595690565` E^(0.16568669119550355` u)] Cos[
          0.0027916963719975653` + 
           179.1021065468981` Log[
             1.4984319905657307`*^-16 + 
              1.` E^(0.16568669119550355` u)]]) Sin[v]), 
  Cos[v] (8.881784197001252`*^-16 + 
     5.927385595690565` E^(0.16568669119550355` u) + 
     0.24346317568406606` Sqrt[
       8.881784197001252`*^-16 + 
        5.927385595690565` E^(0.16568669119550355` u)] Cos[
       0.002791696372037334` + 
        179.1021065468981` Log[
          1.4984319905657304`*^-16 + 
           0.9999999999999998` E^(0.16568669119550355` u)]])}

nn = 24;
Table[ParametricPlot3D[
  surf[u, v], {u, 0, 6 Pi i/nn}, {v, 0, 2 Pi}], {i, 1, nn, 1}];
```

Comment: can you try suppressing the output via `;`, assign a name to the plot (e.g. with a `For[]` loop), and export them instead of displaying them in the notebook?

Comment: Try this too: Do[Print@ParametricPlot3D[
   surf[u, v], {u, 0, 6 Pi i/nn}, {v, 0, 2 Pi}], {i, 1, nn}]

Comment: I apologise, I forgot a semicolon in the crashing code (corrected above). Actually, if I run "Table[...]" it does work and produce the plots, but if I suppress the output with "Table[...];", that is when it crashes! The corrected code above crashes.

Comment: Can you try adding a "list=" before Table[] and reduce nn to 1? Then call "list" in a new line.

Answer (score 1):

Build a `Table` of segments and display the desired number of segments.

```
surf[u_, v_] := {Cos[
     u] (16.958793136378254` E^(0.16568669119550355` u) + \
(1.2436985521695564`*^-15 + 8.299999999999999` E^(0.16568669119550355` u) + 
         0.34091663610461015` Sqrt[
           8.881784197001252`*^-16 + 
            5.927385595690565` E^(0.16568669119550355` u)] Cos[
           0.0027916963719975653` + 
            179.1021065468981` Log[
              1.4984319905657307`*^-16 + 
               1.` E^(0.16568669119550355` u)]]) Sin[v]), 
   Sin[u] (16.958793136378254` E^(0.16568669119550355` u) + \
(1.2436985521695564`*^-15 + 8.299999999999999` E^(0.16568669119550355` u) + 
         0.34091663610461015` Sqrt[
           8.881784197001252`*^-16 + 
            5.927385595690565` E^(0.16568669119550355` u)] Cos[
           0.0027916963719975653` + 
            179.1021065468981` Log[
              1.4984319905657307`*^-16 + 
               1.` E^(0.16568669119550355` u)]]) Sin[v]), 
   Cos[v] (8.881784197001252`*^-16 + 
      5.927385595690565` E^(0.16568669119550355` u) + 
      0.24346317568406606` Sqrt[
        8.881784197001252`*^-16 + 
         5.927385595690565` E^(0.16568669119550355` u)] Cos[
        0.002791696372037334` + 
         179.1021065468981` Log[
           1.4984319905657304`*^-16 + 
            0.9999999999999998` E^(0.16568669119550355` u)]])};

nn = 24;

segments = Table[
   ParametricPlot3D[
    surf[u, v],
    {u, 6 Pi (i - 1)/nn, 6 Pi i/nn}, {v, 0, 2 Pi},
    PlotRange ->
     {{-360, 580}, {-460, 460}, {-150, 150}}],
   {i, nn}];

Manipulate[
 Show[segments[[1 ;; m]]],
 {{m, 24}, 1, nn, 1, ControlType -> Setter}]

Animate[
 Show[segments[[1 ;; m]]],
 {{m, 1}, 1, nn, 1},
 AnimationRate -> 1.25,
 AnimationDirection -> ForwardBackward]
```

Comment: Thank you Bob, this seems to work flawlessly (and I can't quite explain why). However, what I am really aiming for is an animation with very detailed surface plots, such that the rendering may take a minute per frame, for hundreds of frames. My idea was to use the Export[] command to create hundreds of numbered png's. This is why I would prefer a truly sequential treatment, rather than leaving hundreds of detailed surfaces in memory. Plotting truly sequentially seems to fail, no matter if I use Table (like in my original post) or similarly a For loop.

Comment: See [How to | Import and Export Animations](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/howto/ImportAndExportAnimations.html). The `Manipulate` above (built from segments) can be exported directly.